# Filter list items within a Django JSONField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-jsonfield

Here is a simplified version of a Django model I'm working on.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    infos = JSONField()
```

The infos JSONField looks like this :

```
infos = {
    category: "Maths",
    students: [
        {
            name: "Alice",
            result: 8
        },
        {
            name: "Bob",
            result: 12
        }
    ]
}

# (students can have 0 -> n items)
```

I'm trying to get a list of all students that got at least 10 on any course (result >= 10).
However I'm having trouble figuring out a way to filter the QuerySet accordingly.

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
(Course.objects.filter(students__result__gte=10)
               .values_list('students', flat=True))
```

But since students is a list, I can't access directly to the result property of each item. Besides, I don't think it would exclude the "Alice" object from the results.

I'd like to get results like this :

```
items = [
    {
        name: "Bob",
        result: 12
    }
]
```

Bonus points if there is a way to link filtered students and course category :

```
items = [
    {
        category: "Maths",
        students: [
            {
                name: "Bob",
                result: 12
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
```

How can I achieve the desired result ?

Comment: You do not know number of students, yes ?

Comment: I don't know that number in advance which means I can't target array items by their index. I didn't find any "joker" for this, like : students__???__result__gte (where ??? would be replaced in a loop over every student)

Comment: I think you can not implement this using Django's ORM. Because, when you use "spans"(students__result__gte=8). If This condition returns True whole row will be returned. I think you should sort this on the python's side.

Comment: You're right and it makes sense since this is filtering the Course rows and not the students list within the row. Thanks !

Comment: Of course. This will filter on the row level. Good luck !

Comment: I would suggest using **`JSONField`** if your data won’t fit in the database using normal relational modelling. Also, it seems your data is pretty well structured to fit into a relational model

Answer (score 2):

By using raw SQL, I have managed to obtain the result.

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(students_array))
FROM
    course_table,
    json_array_elements(CAST(course_table.infos->>'students' as json)) students_array
WHERE
    CAST(students_array->>'result' as integer) >= 10
;
```

#### Result

```
sample_db=# SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit

sample_db=# select infos from course_table;
{"category": "Maths", "students": [{"name": "Alice", "result": 8}, {"name": "Bob", "result": 12}]}
{"category": "Science", "students": [{"name": "Jerin", "result": 8}, {"name": "George", "result": 12}]}
{"category": "Physics", "students": [{"name": "Vivek", "result": 17}, {"name": "Osama", "result": 6}]}

sample_db=# select array_to_json(array_agg(students_array))
sample_db-# FROM
sample_db-# course_table,
sample_db-#  json_array_elements(CAST(course_table.infos->>'students' as json)) students_array
sample_db-# WHERE
sample_db-#  CAST(students_array->>'result' as integer) >= 10
sample_db-# ;
[{"name": "Bob", "result": 12},{"name": "George", "result": 12},{"name": "Vivek", "result": 17}]
```

---

This raw SQL can be executed by Django as,

```
raw_sql = """
select 1 as id, array_to_json(array_agg(students_array)) as result
FROM
    course_table,
    json_array_elements(CAST(course_table.infos->>'students' as json)) students_array
WHERE
    CAST(students_array->>'result' as integer) >= 10
;
"""
qs = Course.objects.raw(raw_sql)
for i in qs:
    print(i.result)
```

Comment: I interresting to find Django based way

Comment: I know that, But, you can choose this if you haven't ORM based query.

Comment: All of my queries is Django-ORM base

Comment: I hope you already know how to execute the raw SQL using **`.raw(raw_sql)`** method. (if not, check out the updated answer)

Comment: I look for a pure Django-ORM way...without any SQL

Comment: Let's hope someone has a better solution :)

Comment: If you have this exact structure the there is no way to do that with the ORM, see the comment from @gachdavit: `Because, when you use "spans"(students__result__gte=8). If This condition returns True whole row will be returned. I think you should sort this on the python's side`

Answer (score 2):

In case you're using a PostgreSQL database, you can switch to an HStoreField ([docs here][1]). The HStoreField will allow you to use exactly the lookup you mention (`students__result__gte`). Otherwise the most Django-esque way would be to create a Student model like Arakkal suggests in the comments under your question.

EDIT: This is the simplest way to be able to filter given all the maps/dicts are the same (if you really want the same structure as your JSON):

```
class Course(models.Model):
    pass

class Info(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='infos')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # students = models.HStoreField()  # available in postgresql

class Student(models.Model):
    """If not using PostgreSQL, also more Django-esque."""
   info = models.ForeignKey(Info, related_name='students')

   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   result = models.IntegerField()
```

> I'm trying to get a list of all students that got at least 10 on any course (result >= 10)

This would be my prefered structure given your goal and my intuition about the logical relationships:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student, through=Result)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Result(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)
    grade = models.IntegerField()
```

That allows for: `Result.objects.filter(grade__gte=10).values_list('student__name', flat=True)`

Comment: Hi @Jura, My data is not key-value directly, my data structure is a list of keys

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, if it's just a list, then PostgreSQL has the same functionality on ArrayField. (the JSON you posted consists if key-value pairs, no?). If the issue is depth, I'd strongly advise for solving this in the model structure. Could you elaborate on what's the reason you want to use the jsons instead of models?

Comment: I have a array of maps(I do a mistake and write a list of keys), My problem is that I'm blind about length of this array and I havn't any magical query postfix like `__gt` and etc that meaning every item of array.

Comment: Are you sure about the structure of each map, or do they differ? (pretty sure map and dict are the same as a data structure actually)

Comment: Then you'll be imho for sure the happiest down the road using the full Django implementation. I added an implementation above if you'd like to try it out.

Comment: I don't want a new design of databse relations, I need a way to fetching my data from my current model

Comment: There is unfortunatelly no way to do SQL lookups (except for Arakkal's answer obviously, but no native way) on JSON fields in relational DBs, so there can't be a Django ORM way to do it. I'm afraid you'll have to choose either a different model architecture, or your DB entirely (MongoDB for example works like a giant JSON).

Comment: Thank you and don't worry @jura-brazdil, I'm sure about what I doing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) for your Course Class. This would enable you to make the query you want in the Django-ORM style without using raw SQL.

PS:- I"ll edit this answer with more code and details if this suits your needs.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil-Khandelwal, I want handle this problem by aggregation things same as F, Func, Cast I dont want any SQL in anywhere.